# Present Perfect and Present Continuous

Tags: tense

Friend: It has been a month now.

Me:
A: Time has been going fast.
B: Time is going fast.

Would the first sentence (A) mean that the time has been fast for 1 month and the other that it was fast before 1 month and is still now (meaning currently) or vice versa?

Comment: Me: Time flies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical difference here between the PrPf continuous and the Pr continuous. The PrPf version may be employed to imply a *little* more strongly that the past month has passed faster than you expected, and the Pr version may be employed to imply a *little* more strongly that you expect the time to continue passing at the current rate for some time to come; but few speakers are concerned about such very subtle points in such a casual conversation as you describe, where the speakers are unlikely to mean anything in particular.

In a different conversation, of course, the distinction might be more strongly marked:

**A**: It's been a month now.
**B**: That long? Doesn't seem like it. I guess *time's been going fast*.
**A**: Bob?
**B**: Yeah?
**A**: It's been a month. That report is due Monday.
**B**: Hmm ... You're right. *Time's going fast*. Guess I'd better get some data.
**A**: Jeez, Bob, you haven't even got the data yet?!
**B**: Well, not *today's* data. He-who-shall-not-be-named will want that folded in before I print the report.
**A**: You mean you've already written it?
**B**: Al, *time's been going fast*—but not as fast as me.

Answer (score 0):

Friend: It's been month now. [more idiomatic to use the contraction]

Me: A: Time has been going fast.

Me: B: Time is going fast.

A = Time, **starting in the past until this moment of speaking has been going fast.**
It does not imply it is going fast now.

B = Time is going fast.
**That is a general statement about time**. Whether yours or your friend's "time".